# python ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to coding, I couldn't get pycharm to work (i kept getting an error saying "failed to create virtual environment") so i used this link

https://www.ianmaddaus.com/post/manage-multiple-versions-python-mac/

to uninstall all pythons except 2.7 in the bash profile (2 of them stayed)
edit: this is what i did to delete all the versions of python except 2.7:
i opened the bash profile, deleted all the versions of python - i did not delete version 2.7, even though there were 2 of the same version in the bash profile, because i heard mac needs python 2.7 to function and i didn't want to mess with that. then i typed in the terminal the following code:

```
sudo rm -rf '/Applications/Python 3.10'
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python3
```

now when i try to run python from the terminal i get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

and when i try to run python3 from the terminal i get this error:

```
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000104dcce00 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

when i try doing this:

```
unset PYTHONPATH
unset PYTHONHOME
```

they both work (both python and python3) but they start giving the errors above again when i try later

what did i do wrong?

Comment: When you say, "uninstall all pythons except 2.7 in the bash profile (2 of them stayed)", what do you mean exactly? What are the exact steps you performed, and what was the outcome exactly? Please [edit] to clarify. I probably won't be much help myself since I don't use Mac, but someone else should see it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for more tips.

Comment: i opened the bash profile, deleted all the versions of python - i did not delete version 2.7, even though there were 2 of the same version in the bash profile, because i heard mac needs python 2.7 to function and i didn't want to mess with that. then i typed in the terminal the following code:                                 
 sudo rm -rf '/Applications/Python 3.10'
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: [edit] the question. Comments don't support fancy formatting.

Comment: i already edited it